# How to run a winform project for more than one?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I wonder that can we run a c# project for two times which contains several solutions inside it. For example We have runned our project firstly then we have have button which is start new one. I writed this code for 'start new button': `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new FormName_Main());`

But this does not work as I want. Also I used the same code with Program.cs class.
Can someone tell me that how to run this project without closing the first one?

Comment: Right click on project -> Debug -> Start new instance?

Comment: Or right click your Solution -> Set StartUp Projects... It is unclear what projects you want to start and from where. Please explain your situation somewhat more explicitly.

Comment: You need to display two different forms or start two different processes?

Comment: The way the question is written, it doesn't make much sense. Either you are asking how to start a different project from inside Visual Studio, or you are asking how to start different executables. The second case is obvious. For debugging:  1) solutions contain projects, not the other way round. 2) you *can* change the startup project just by right clicking on the one you want to be the new startup project. 3) You can start debugging any instance from Debug > Start New Instance

Comment: You cant do that. Just open separate visual studio projects and run the application.

Comment: If I get you correct you have a start new button which should start a second instance of the application? If so you have a problem with how you do it. You need to either run a commandline command to start the .exe again when you click the button or call the new Nikola_Main() inside a new thread/process. although the later is probably not what you are looking for if you also have a gui display. thus I would say the first method for you there

Comment: Thank you all. I tried somethings and @oguz-ozgul sharing works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
Process.Start(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. This works fine for me.

Comment: Then can you please mark it as answer? :) Thanks